# How can I change lower to upper using (three) parameters in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames, rename

1. I have to make a bash script that will be changing files' names from lower to upper OR from upper to lower via parameters in command line. So when I put in command line:

./bashScript lower upper

then all files in directory should change from lower to upper case.

2. I have to also add 3rd parameter that will let me change only one specific file. So for example I have to be able of putting in command line:

   ./bashScript lower upper fileName

Comment: Watch out for renaming the script itself :)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095474/how-can-i-change-lower-to-upper-using-three-parameters

Comment: Homework / classwork?

Comment: Why two parameters? Can you do upper upper, or lower lower? What have you tried so far? Can you convert one file to lower-case? ( a first step )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bash` operators to change the case of variables are `${var^^*}` for to-upper and `${var,,*}` for to-lower, so:

```
#! /bin/bash -
die() { printf >&2 '%s\n' "$@"; exit 1; }
usage() { die "Usage:" "  $0 "{"lower upp","upper low"}"er [files]"; }

(( $# >= 2 )) || usage 
from=$1 to=$2; shift 2

[[ $from   =  @(upper|lower) ]] &&
[[ $to     =  @(upper|lower) ]] &&
[[ "$from" != "$to"          ]] || usage

shopt -s nullglob dotglob
IFS= ret=0

(( $# > 0 )) || set -- *[[:$from:]]*

for file do
  case $to in
    (upper) newfile=${file^^*};;
    (lower) newfile=${file,,*};;
  esac
  [[ "$file" = "$newfile" ]] ||
    echo mv -i -- "$file" "$newfile" ||
    ret=$?
done
exit "$ret"
```

Remove the `echo` when you're done testing.

Answer (score 0):

If not homework then use Larry Wall's `rename`

- `rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *` to convert to lower-case.
- `rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' *` to convert to upper-case.

I don't know if this works for all languages, but it is the example in the manual.